# How to SELECT FROM a identifier of a sub query

Tags: sql, oracle

Why I can't SELECT FROM a identifier of a sub query?

```
SELECT e.num_enc "Codigo Encomenda", e.data_enc "Data Encomenda", a.quantidade "Quantidade"
FROM encomendas e, (SELECT e.num_enc num_enc,SUM(i.quantidade) quantidade
                FROM itens i, encomendas e
                WHERE i.num_enc = e.num_enc AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM e.data_enc)=2014
                GROUP BY e.num_enc) a,
               (SELECT AVG(b.quantidade) media
                FROM (SELECT SUM(i.quantidade) quantidade
                      FROM a) c #PROBLEM HERE
WHERE e.num_enc = a.num_enc AND a.quantidade>c.media;
```

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, but you already found out your approach isn't valid. What is this query supposed to do? Also, comma separated table lists in the `FROM` has been replaced by ANSI `JOIN` syntax well over 20 years ago.

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  You have written a syntactically incorrect SQL statement and asked "why is the syntax incorrect?".  Because you haven't used SQL correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO, you are trying to select from inline view / subquery immediately which can't be done. You can access that subquery in outer query (OR) you can `JOIN` with it and get the data.

For your purpose, you can consider using a CTE (Unless you are using `MySQL`).

You can re-write your query to be like

```
SELECT e.num_enc "Codigo Encomenda", 
e.data_enc "Data Encomenda", 
a.quantidade "Quantidade"
FROM encomendas e
JOIN (SELECT e.num_enc num_enc,SUM(i.quantidade) quantidade
                FROM itens i, encomendas e
                WHERE i.num_enc = e.num_enc AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM e.data_enc)=2014
                GROUP BY e.num_enc) a ON e.num_enc = a.num_enc;
```

This below part (where error comes) looks illogical to me since you are trying to get `AVG()` from `SUM()` result

```
 (SELECT AVG(b.quantidade) media
            FROM (SELECT SUM(i.quantidade) quantidade
                  FROM a) c #PROBLEM HERE
```